# Why an samba admin user cannot login

Tags: samba

- Samba： 4.4.9
- centos： 7
- `smb.conf` relative code

```
[share]
        path = /home/lingo/share
        browseable = No
        admin users = pi
        guest ok = Yes
        read only = No
        valid users = hhh
        write list = hhh
```

- Access condition

[image]

- Question

  1. **Why pi, as an admin user, cannot login, while hhh can do it ？**
- Operation I tried
  After adding pi into the **valid users**, it works.
- Others
  I have reboot the smbd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`valid users` determines who can connect

`admin users` determines who can perform operations as root

Take a look at this table:

https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch09.html#samba2-CHP-9-TABLE-1